# Wrong `nbytes` value in a numpy array after broadcasting with `broadcast_to`

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I just noted this:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys

arr = np.broadcast_to(0, (10, 1000000000000))
print(arr.nbytes)  # prints "80000000000000"
print(sys.getsizeof(arr))  # prints "120"
```

Is this a bug or intended behavior? I.e., is `nbytes` meant to hold the amount of "logical" bytes, not accounting for 0-strides?

Comment: I don't see any relevant discussion (closed or open) on the NumPy [issue tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues), and the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html) don't say anything about this. Maybe open an issue on the tracker? (The most likely resolution is just adding a note to the docs, since correctly reporting the true "physical" memory consumption gets tricky for weird strides, and changing the behavior would have significant backward compatibility problems.)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html), nbytes is calculated similarly to
`np.prod(arr.shape) * arr.itemsize`. `arr.base.nbytes` returns 8 (the amount of physical memory consumed by the elements). `getsizeof` returns the size of python's protocol buffer object. I don't see where this is supposed to be a bug.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny the docs say: "Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array." This result, however, is definitely not the number of bytes consumed. Also, what you refer to is the line in an example demonstrating two ways of calculating a quantity, it's never stated that that is the way `nbytes` is calculated.

Comment: With any `view` there will be a difference between `nbtyes` and `getsizeof`, since the `view` doesn't own its own data.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the suggestion, I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22925) on the tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't see it documented, `nbytes` does look like the product of shape and `itemsize`, or `arr.size*arr.itemsize`.

In all examples I've looked at `nbytes` uses the arrays of shape/size, not that of its `base`.  So I wouldn't read too much into the "consumed" used in the docs.

Your example:

```
In [117]: arr = np.broadcast_to(0,(1,2,3))

In [119]: arr.shape, arr.strides, arr.nbytes
Out[119]: ((1, 2, 3), (0, 0, 0), 24)

In [120]: arr.base
Out[120]: array(0)

In [121]: arr.base.nbytes
Out[121]: 4
```

The broadcasted array is a `view` of a much smaller one; `nbytes` reflects its own shape, not the shape of the base.

To take another example, where the `view` is a subset of the base:

```
In [122]: np.arange(100).nbytes
Out[122]: 400

In [123]: np.arange(100)[::4].nbytes
Out[123]: 100
```

The code for `broadcast_to` is viewable at `np.lib.stride_tricks._broadcast_to`.  It uses `np.nditer` to generate the new view.

`sys.getsizeof` does a reasonable job of returning memory use for an array with its on data (i.e. `base` is `None`).  It does not provide any useful information for a `view`.

### sliding_windows

Another example of striding tricks used to make a "larger" array:

```
In [180]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4).copy()

In [181]: arr.shape, arr.strides, arr.nbytes
Out[181]: ((4, 4), (16, 4), 64)

In [182]: res = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(2,2))

In [183]: res.shape, res.strides, res.nbytes
Out[183]: ((3, 3, 2, 2), (16, 4, 16, 4), 144)
```

It's a `view` of the original (4,4) `arr`:

```
In [184]: res.base
Out[184]: <numpy.lib.stride_tricks.DummyArray at 0x1fa8e7cc730>

In [185]: res.base.base
Out[185]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [186]: res.base.base is arr
Out[186]: True
```